# Why the php script doesnt send me mail at intervals?

Tags: php, email, cron, cron-task

I've created a simple php script to send an email :

email.php

---

```
<?php $message = "This is the message"; 
   mail('something@unusual.com', 'Dummy Subject', $message); ?>
```

Then , defined the schedule at crontab as follows :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/file/email.php
```

When I check the cron daemon with

```
ps -ef | grep crond
```

command, it shows up. Looks alive.

I expect to get an email in every passing minute. But when I check with the

```
mail
```

command , it responds as "No mail for somethingunusual".

And I do not observe any incoming mails so far. Not even under /var/mail.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you own unusual.com? If so... congrats! If not, it seems like you're probably trying to send email to the wrong place. Maybe you want `somethingunusual@localhost`?

Comment: Yes I have @Alex